# Revision history summary

Tags: 7, nodes

I am looking for a solution to show a summary of revision history for all nodes in one place. The out of the box solution is to show a revision history for each node apart. I want to be able to track my content admins' changes in one place (I couldn't find a module that does what I want)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, you can configure any list of revisions. You also can add filter/sort logic, pager, configure access and much more useful things.
[image]

You always can export your solution with Views export or with Features module and reuse it on other Drupal sites.

More information about Views: http://nodeone.se/en/node/20

Answer (score 0):

There are severel modules that extend revision, one of this is [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning).

Another way is create a view of revisions.